# Display data from multiple list in a single view

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a SharePoint 2013 application in which i have different list, based on which the user the fills the item into the form. Now the first scenario where i'm stuck is that when an user is logged in to the application, he can fill only one form i.e only one item per list as he can only apply for the service once. So how do i manage this, I know there is something that can be done custom where we can kind of bind some id's but i want to achieve this by using the out of box functionalities in SharePoint. Now my second question is, when the user has filled all the applications/services by filling the item in each list. There is a column in each list which shows whether the application is accepted or rejected. So for example i have 10 list in which i have this column, now i want to fetch the items which are approved from each list and want to show it on one single list and vice versa for the rejected item. How can i achieve this ?

I thought of creating a view but then I got stuck on how to create a view where i can fetch items from multiple list.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

To tackle scenario 1, you could create a a people and group column let's say "Requestor" and make it mandatory and unique. Instruct all the users manually type in their name in the Requestor field. So if a person has already filled in the form , when he does again he will be prompted with unique validation. This is not a full proof solution but something which you can acheive OOTB very quickly.

For scenario 2 , you should consider Content search webparts

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just has a doubt for scenario 1 : In case if we do so then the other user with same name will also not be able to fill in the form.